# Asignar valores a una columna basándose en la información de otra

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Sucede que tengo la siguiente matriz con la variable Data:

```
Data

Product1
1234
5678
Product2
8910
1112
Product3
1314
1516
```

Y tengo esta información contenida de la Variable Product y su respectivo Valor en una matriz, de la siguiente manera:

```
Product  Value

Product1 1
Product2 2
Product3 3
```

Necesito organizar la matriz con esta información, con el fin de que quede de la siguiente manera:

```
Data     Product  Value

1234     Product1 1
5678     Product1 1
8910     Product2 2
1112     Product2 2
1314     Product3 3
1516     Product3 3
```

Espero que quede claro mi cuestionamiento.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Pues no está del todo claro... Las matrices que tienes ¿en qué estructura de datos python están guardadas? ¿Son listas o diccionarios? ¿Arrays numpy? ¿ Dataframes pandas? Si es lo último ¿podrías mostrar cómo lo muestra pandas para comprender mejor su estructura? ¿Cuáles son los nombres de columna o el índice?

Comment: Sucede que lo que propongo es un ejemplo

Comment: Los datos que tengo son leídos por medio de `pandas.read_csv``, por ende ese es el foramto que tengo de los datos

Comment: Pero aún no me queda clara la estructura del dataframe. `Data` ¿es el nombre de una variable que contiene los datos o es el título de alguna columna o índice? `Product1`, `Product2`... ¿son nombres de columnas? Si es así ¿por qué los has puesto unos debajo de otros en lugar de en forma de tabla? Si no es así ¿Qué son? ¿Son valores de algunas filas que están actuando como si fueran un título de lo que va luego?

Comment: Exacto, Data es el nombre de la variable que contiene tanto datos numericos como caracteres, en este caso los caractereres son aquellos que comienzan por Product List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver si lo entendí correctamente. Tenemos un dataframe con una sola columna "Data", en la que aparecen mezcladas filas con números y otras con texto, que actúa a modo de titulo de los números que van después. Así:

```
>>> print(df)
       Data
0  Product1
1      1234
2      5678
3  Product2
4      8910
5      1112
6  Product3
7      1314
8      1516
```

Lo que quieres es extraer a qué producto pertenece cada número, de modo que podamos construir otro dataframe en la que una columna "Data" tenga solo los números, y haya otra columna "Product" que tenga el nombre del producto. Lo de tener una columna adicional con el "Value" sería más sencillo una vez tenemos identificado el producto.

Lo más complicado es lo de sacar el nombre del producto, ya que eso implica una interrelación entre las filas de `df`, puesto que un nombre como `Product1` afecta a todos los números que le siguen, hasta que aparezca otro nombre como `Product2`.

Después de darle unas cuantas vueltas, no se me ha ocurrido una solución mejor que la siguiente. No me gusta porque es confusa y farragosa, y porque tengo la sensación de que tiene que haber una forma más sencilla, pero al menos funciona. Se trata de:

- Usar `groupby()` para agrupar todas las filas de `df` que tengan un criterio común, en este caso referirse a un mismo producto. Para ello usaré la capacidad que tiene `groupbuy()` de admitir como parámetro una función, a la que llamará pasándole cada valor del index y usando el valor retornado por esta para agrupar. Usaré esta función para retornar el mismo valor mientras no cambie el nombre del producto.
- Usar `apply()` para aplicar otra función a cada grupo. En este caso la función recibirá un `Series` con los datos del grupo, y retornará como resultado otro dataframe que construiré mediante un diccionario que especificará las tres columnas que voy a poner en el datagrama resultante. Una columna será el nombre del producto (que es el primer elemento del grupo), otra con los datos (que son los restantes elementos del grupo) y otra con el valor (que obtengo de otro dataframe, `df2` que sería como el que has mostrado en la pregunta).

Este es el código:

```python
anterior = None

def agrupar(ind):
  global anterior
  if ind.startswith("Product") and ind != anterior:
    anterior = ind
  return anterior

def sacar_dict(fila):
  product = fila.values[0]
  return pd.DataFrame({ "Product": product, "Data": fila.values[1:], "Value": df2.loc[product].Value})

grupos = df.set_index("Data", drop=False).groupby(agrupar)
resultado = grupos.Data.apply(sacar_dict).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Resultado:

```
   Data   Product  Value
0  1234  Product1      1
1  5678  Product1      1
2  8910  Product2      2
3  1112  Product2      2
4  1314  Product3      3
5  1516  Product3      3
```

Comment: Muchas gracias abulafia, voy a intentarlo a ver que tal me sale.